# Assign to an arbitrarily deep array index?

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array which corresponds to successively recursive keys in another array, what is the best way to to assign a value to that "path" (if you want to call it that)?

For example:

```
$some_array = array();
$path = array('a','b','c');
set_value($some_array,$path,'some value');
```

Now, `$some_array` should equal

```
array(
  'a' => array(
    'b' => array(
      'c' => 'some value'
)))
```

At the moment, I am using the following:

```
function set_value(&$dest,$path,$value) {
  $addr = "\$dest['" . implode("']['", $path) . "']";
  eval("$addr = \$value;");
}
```

Obviously, this is a very naive approach and poses a security risk, so how would you do it?

Comment: What happens if the path is invalid?

Comment: @konforce - It should assign anyways, like in my example above when `$some_example` starts empty.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that. Note it also now overwrites string values with arrays, but that would be simple to change if that behavior is not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive solution (not tested):

```
 function set_value(&$dest,$path,$value) {
      $index=array_shift($path);
      if(empty($path)){
        // on last level
        $dest[$index]=$value;
      }
      else{
        // descending to next level
        set_value($dest[$index],$path,$value);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow, reminds me of Lisp.

Yea, `eval` is generally not the best idea.

Personally, I would simply iterate:

```
function set_value(&$dest,$path,$value) {
  $val =& $dest;
  for($i = 0; $i > count($path) - 1; $i++) {
     $val =& $val[$i];
  }

  $val[$path[$i]] = $value;
}
```

If you're in PHP 5 you can probably get rd of some of those '&' too

Comment: Do you mean `$val[$path[$i]]` where you have `$val[$i]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
function set_value(&$dest, $path, $value)
{
  # allow for string paths of a/b/c
  if (!is_array($path)) $path = explode('/', $path);

  $a = &$dest;
  foreach ($path as $p)
  {
    if (!is_array($a)) $a = array();
    $a = &$a[$p];
  }

  return $a = $value;
}


set_value($a, 'a/b/c', 'foo');
```

Updated to work with keys that don't yet exist, and to accept either an array or a string path.

Answer (score 2):

```
function set_value(&$dest, $path, $value) {
    $dest = array(array_pop($path) => $value);
    for($i = count($path) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $dest = array($path[$i] => $dest);
    }
}
```