# Accessing an arbitrarily deep key in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I have an array that contains `['key1', 'key2', 'key3']` is there any way to map this to an array `$array['key1']['key2']['key3']` without using loops or eval()?

Example of an array:

```
$var = [
    'key1' => [
        'subkey1' => [
            'finalkey' => 'value',
        ],
        'subkey' => [
            'otherkey' => 'value',
        ],
    ],
    'key2' => 'blah'
];
```

And then I have an array like this:

```
$keys = ['key1', 'subkey1', 'finalkey']
```

or

```
$keys = ['key1', 'subkey']
```

Comment: Methinks your concept is probably wrong

Comment: How are you expecting to iterate through an array without a loop?

Comment: I've only been able to do this with loops or eval. Is there any reason not to do this with `eval()` if the input can be trusted? Also, I was just wondering if there was some way to do this in PHP that I wasn't aware of, that might be better.

Comment: @RogueCoder, there are many reasons for not using `eval`, including performance.

Comment: The use of `eval()` is discouraged. If you're relying on it, there likely exists another way to accomplish the same thing that doesn't use `eval()`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using loops right now. I was just curious if there was a better way or if I was doing it right.

Comment: @Rogue Coder, it seems like a silly restriction to not "use loops." PHP function calls are slow. (e.g., Tim's recursive solution is nearly twice as slow as the iterative one that I gave on PHP 5.4.)

Comment: @Matthew Thanks, I plan to keep using the loops solution I have now (Basically the same as what you posted). I was just wondering if there were other solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function array_find($needle, &$haystack)
{
    $current = array_shift($needle);
    if(!isset($haystack[$current]))
    {
        return null;
    }
    if(!is_array($haystack[$current]))
    {
        return $haystack[$current];
    }
    return array_find($needle, $haystack[$current]);
}
```

Comment: Why pass `$haystack` by reference?

Comment: @Matthew:  To avoid unnecessary copying of the arrays.

Comment: PHP shouldn't make any copies if you don't modify the arrays. e.g., `$a = [range(0,100000)]; $b = $a[0]` doesn't make a copy. AFAIK, neither should your routines, but PHP does still surprise me from time to time...

Comment: @Matthew - It makes copies every time the function is invoked.

Comment: @nickb, which function? PHP doesn't copy unless you modify the array. See http://codepad.org/hcngGubU. The same amount of memory is used regardless of the reference. If copying were happening the max memory for the non-referenced version should go through the roof with 50 copies. References in PHP are generally useless unless you need them to write to aliased data.

Comment: @Matthew - It would make sense that it internally implements copy-on-write, but I can't find such information in the documentation. Does it exist?

Comment: It's not mentioned very often, except for in user comments. Here's one place describing the ZE: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, comes from a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6415785/259778) to a different question.

```
function get_value($dest, $path)
{
  # allow for string paths of a/b/c
  if (!is_array($path)) $path = explode('/', $path);

  $a = $dest;
  foreach ($path as $p)
  {
    if (!is_array($a)) return null;
    $a = $a[$p];
  }

  return $a;
}
```

This should perform better than recursive solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following non-recursive method for my [personal framework](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/64362af4f05b76c2439f91a240b388a958c3d0de/phunction.php#L692):

```
function Value($data, $key = null, $default = false)
{
    if (isset($key) === true)
    {
        if (is_array($key) !== true)
        {
            $key = explode('.', $key);
        }

        foreach ((array) $key as $value)
        {
            $data = (is_object($data) === true) ? get_object_vars($data) : $data;

            if ((is_array($data) !== true) || (array_key_exists($value, $data) !== true))
            {
                return $default;
            }

            $data = $data[$value];
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Usage:

```
var_dump(Value($array, 'key1.subkey1.finalkey')); // or
var_dump(Value($array, array('key1', 'subkey1', 'finalkey')));
```

It could be further simplified by removing the object and default value support, as well as other checks.

Comment: It's worth noting that doing something like this is over 100x slower than directly accessing the keys. `$array['a']['b']['c']['d']` vs `Value($array, 'a.b.c.d')`. If you count on this for common items like config values then it's not unreasonable to think you might have 80 look-ups in one page resulting in an extra 0.020s cost (about the same cost as database query).

Comment: @Xeoncross: Hi David! Here is a quick benchmark (http://codepad.org/cRbdxTyg), I get an average of 10x slower using `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` array notation.