# How to search array at certain depth?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having a multidimensional array with many depth , since I have around 9 dimension so I going to show my code on how I accessing them

sample code:

```
$attribute[5]['group'][1]['f'][4]['id'][18]['fc'][20]
```

[sample array](https://jsfiddle.net/dqtfq550/)

Is there any way to get the array base on the depth and key I want , **without knowing the level before it**

lets say I have only partial information like key 20(the last key) , **Is there any way to get the array at the 9th dimension with key 20**?

Ideal function should look like this

```
function get_by_depth($m_array,$depth,$key){

}

$array=get_by_depth($attribute,9,20);
//will search through available level 9 item
//if there are key 20 at level 9 return the array or value
```

Comment: Can you write what an ideal function signature would look like for this use case? I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking. Do you want to take in both a dimension and a key or just a key?

Comment: Maybe this other SO question can give you some helpful ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320449/accessing-an-arbitrarily-deep-key-in-a-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work using your sample array data.

```
function get_by_depth($array, $depth, $key, $currentDepth = 0)
{
    if ($currentDepth == $depth) {

        return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : null;

    } else {

        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {

            if (is_array($v)) {
                return get_by_depth($v, $depth, $key, ++$currentDepth);
            }

        }

    }

}


echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_by_depth($array,8,'image'));exit;
```

**Note**
This assumes that every array only contains at most a single array inside of it. If you need a solution that can handle arrays that contain multiple arrays at the same level of depth then there would be a lot more work to do

Comment: I need solution for array that can handle arrays that contain multiple arrays at the same level of depth. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

One way is using recursion

```
function recursive($array, $searchKey){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        //If $value is an array.
        If($searchKey == $key){
           echo $value; //or do something now that it is found
           break;
        }
        if(is_array($value)){
            //We need to loop through it.
            recursive($value, $searchKey);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the array have same key value at different depth?

Answer (score 0):

```
function depth(&$array, $depth_level = 0) {
    $cdepth = 0;
    while($a = array_shift($array)) { $cdepth++;
        if($depth_level==$cdepth) return $a;
    }
    return $array;
}
```