# Get array value from multiple variables

Tags: php, json

So I have a string $key which is something along the lines of  `system.style.background` which I explode at character '.' to $exp. I also have some decoded JSON `$system`.

I would like to do something like this

```
echo $system[$exp[0]][$exp[1]][$exp[2]]
```

which would be

```
echo $system["system"]["style"]["background"]
```

However, $key could be any string, with n amount of delimiters. Such as

- system
- system.style
- system.style.background
- system.style.background.description

How would I write a function that takes a string and returns the json value like above?

Edit: A jank way of doing it would be

```
if(isset($exp[0])){
    $config[$exp[0]];
}

if(isset($exp[1])){
    $config[$exp[0]][$exp[1]];
}

if(isset($exp[n])){
    $config[$exp[0]][$exp[1]][$exp[n]];
}
```

Edit: Not duplicate because this is an associative array

Comment: Please specify your problem

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing an arbitrarily deep key in a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320449/accessing-an-arbitrarily-deep-key-in-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently PHP is missing a built in function to access deep arrays of dynamic depth. But it can be done with the infamous [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.eval.php) function. Read the linked disclaimer and use with care.

```
$system["system"]["style"]["background"]["description"] = "found it";

$input = "system.style.background.description";
$exp = explode(".", $input);

$code = '$system';
foreach ($exp as $level) $code .= "['$level']";

eval("\$result = $code;");
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the solution and thank you for linking the disclaimer.

Comment: Not sure where `'system.style.background.description'` is actually coming from in the OP's question, but definitely do your validation checks on the `$level` variable before blindly tossing it in. As far as security impact levels are concerned when dealing with remote applications/endpoints, things like the code above are an absolute critical vulnerability, and if `$input` is provided by the user, then the code above would result in an *extremely* insecure server. Not knocking the solution, but definitely do your due diligence to sanitize the input.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you are asking but this may solve your problem :)

```
$config = ...
$exp = ...
$i = 0;

while (isset($exp[$i])){
    $config = $config[$exp[$i]];
    ++$i;
}

$config // There you have your final config
```